# How to add a file into the project just before deploying the code into Heroku server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

A requirement where I need to aad files (Like .txt or .eml) from S3 into the project just before deploying the code into the Heroku server. I can do this on my local machine by creating a commit but in this case, that file will be downloaded into my local machine. 
We don't want to download the file into my local machine just wanted to add that file into the project that it can de available during the deployment.
So someone guides me that How to download content from S3 and include it to build slug or package during deployment.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use a pre-commit hook in git to download the file and push it to Heroku. Or just scrap whatever half-baked idea you're pursuing. Since Heroku has a ephemeral file system you can't just "download it later to the server". Heroku resets the file system frequently from your latest push. https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit of work, but you could look into implementing your own buildpack for this app. Heroku supports multiple buildpacks that are executed (in order) on your app when your app is built as part of the deploy process, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#creating-a-buildpack for more details. After running the language builpack, your buildpack could download the file, which will then be available to your Dynos when the app has finished building and is being run.